# Using erldis on ejabberd Module?

Tags: module, redis, ejabberd

I'm working on an ejabberd module that requires erldis.
I'm having problems starting the rldis application from in the ejabberd module initialization.
Any tips, tutorial on how to integrate? Which files are required to be copied to ejabberd/ebin? What is the recommended start sequence?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this example of using Redis with ejabberd:
http://logicalfriday.com/2011/06/30/ejabberd-global-roster/

A quick read shows that it is not totally integrated in ejabberd (even in term of start / stop), but that can help.

I do not know what your module is supposed to do, so it is hard to suggest a better approach at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

I did similar here: https://github.com/bob-p/mod_global_roster this might give you a few pointers.